# SQL Update column values using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

In a MySQL database table, I want to `UPDATE` some rows with the results from a query.

For instance, I have a table

```
TABLE employees(
  employeeId int,
  salary int,
)
```

and I want to `UPDATE` only the rows that appear in the below query, with `employeeId`s matching and with `newSalary` becoming the modified value for `salary`

```
(SELECT employeeId, newSalary FROM ....)
```

I originally thought to load the results into a temporary table, but I'm not sure how to get the `SET` value, as illustrated here

```
UPDATE employees
SET salary = (???)
WHERE employeeId exists in tempTable
```

You might comment that this results in denormalization, I'm aware of this. I suspect there will be some "you don't want to do this" type responses, for the sake of brevity, please just assume I have a good reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Join the subquery and your table you gonna updating:

```
UPDATE employees x INNER JOIN (
    SELECT employeeId, newSalary FROM ....
) y ON x.employeeId=y.employeeId
SET x.salary=y.newSalary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update employees, tempTable
set employees.salary=tempTable.newSalary
wnere employees.employeeId=tempTable.employeeId;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update employees
inner join temptable
on employees.employeeid = temptable.employeeid
set employees.salary = temptable.newsalary
```